# Combine two dataframes according to a common column with missing values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes that share a common column named `date`.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date': ["2021-06-01 08:00:00", "2021-06-01 08:01:00", "2021-06-01 08:02:00", "2021-06-01 08:03:00", "2021-06-01 08:04:00"], 'x1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})

                  date  x1
0  2021-06-01 08:00:00   1
1  2021-06-01 08:01:00   2
2  2021-06-01 08:02:00   3
3  2021-06-01 08:03:00   4
4  2021-06-01 08:04:00   5
```

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'date': ["2021-06-01 08:00:00", "2021-06-01 08:01:00", "2021-06-01 08:04:00"], 'x2': [11, 22, 55]})

                  date  x2
0  2021-06-01 08:00:00  11
1  2021-06-01 08:01:00  22
2  2021-06-01 08:04:00  55
```

First, I need to mention that `df1` does not contain missing `date`, only `df2`. Now, I want to add `df2` `x2` to `df1` according to the `date` column. For missing values, I need to add something silly like string `MISSING` or `NaN`. How should I achieve this in python?

For example, dates  `"2021-06-01 08:02:00", "2021-06-01 08:03:00"` are missing in `df2`. So, resulting `df1`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date': ["2021-06-01 08:00:00", "2021-06-01 08:01:00", "2021-06-01 08:02:00", "2021-06-01 08:03:00", "2021-06-01 08:04:00"], 'x1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'x2': [11, 22, np.nan, np.nan, 55]})

                  date  x1    x2
0  2021-06-01 08:00:00   1  11.0
1  2021-06-01 08:01:00   2  22.0
2  2021-06-01 08:02:00   3   NaN
3  2021-06-01 08:03:00   4   NaN
4  2021-06-01 08:04:00   5  55.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

`import pandas as pd`

`pd.merge(df1,df2, how='left', on='date')`

```
 date  x1    x2
0  2021-06-01 08:00:00   1  11.0
1  2021-06-01 08:01:00   2  22.0
2  2021-06-01 08:02:00   3   NaN
3  2021-06-01 08:03:00   4   NaN
4  2021-06-01 08:04:00   5  55.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
out = df1.merge(df2, how='outer') # or how='left' if you're sure df1 as all dates.
print(out)
```

Output:

```
                  date  x1    x2
0  2021-06-01 08:00:00   1  11.0
1  2021-06-01 08:01:00   2  22.0
2  2021-06-01 08:02:00   3   NaN
3  2021-06-01 08:03:00   4   NaN
4  2021-06-01 08:04:00   5  55.0
```